# Why are empty collections of different type equal?

Tags: java, collections, testng

What is mechanism below that makes equal different types?

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
```

```
@Test
public void whyThisIsEqual() {
    assertEquals(new HashSet<>(), new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `assertEquals(Collection<?> actual, Collection<?> expected)` [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) says:

> Asserts that two collections contain the same elements in the same order. If they do not, an AssertionError is thrown.

Thus the content of the collections will be compared which, in case both the collections are empty, are equal.

Answer (score 31):

They are not...

```
System.out.println(new HashSet<>().equals(new ArrayList<>())); // false
```

This is specific to `testng` `assertEquals`

Looking at the documentation of that method it says:

> Asserts that two collections contain the same elements in the same order.

And this is ridiculous to me, a `Set` does not have an order, per-se.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("hello");
set.add("from");
set.add("jug");

System.out.println(set); // [from, hello, jug]

IntStream.range(0, 1000).mapToObj(x -> x + "").forEachOrdered(set::add);
IntStream.range(0, 1000).mapToObj(x -> x + "").forEachOrdered(set::remove);

System.out.println(set); // [jug, hello, from]
```

So comparing these against a `Collection` at *some particular* point in time would yield interesting results.

Even worse, `java-9` `Set::of` methods implement a randomization internally, so the *order* (or not the order) will be different from run to run.

Comment: I find that a dangerous choice from junit to call `assetEquals` but not use `Object.equals`... this lead to "unexpected" behavior like this one.

Comment: @AxelH indeed, I was really not expecting this

Comment: Junit throws an `AssertionError` here. It is testng which has this behaviour. (I see you edited your answer right when I posted this comment)

Comment: @marstran see another edit, I find this a very very weird

Comment: An easier way to change the order is to play with the capacity and load factor.

Comment: Should probably report this to the testng people. They can't treat all collections as ordered.

Comment: @AxelH & Eugene, I agree, this method is misnamed. This should be named something like assertEqualContentsOrdered. It would be useful for comparing a list and a set, in the case that you know that the set is ordered. (There is already assertEqualsNoOrder but it only takes arrays.)

Comment: Sets don't have an order, but there isn't any for the test framework to know this from the `Collections` interface. I'd argue that the test methods shouldn't have been implemented this way, really. For comparison, Python's unittest library's `assertEqual` is a simple `==` (akin to `equals` in Java) check. Then there is separate methods for things like `assertSequenceEqual`, `assertItemsEqual`, etc, which make it clearer how they are handling collections.

Comment: Oh, also, people are mentioning JUnit here. I initially thought it was that, too (I've never seen anyone use anything else in Java), but it's a totally different framework, some TestNG. JUnit does not have this issue. [There's no `Collection` type overrides](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html), so it should be using the `equals` method of the collection.

Answer (score 9):

Testng calls through to a method implemented this way.

```
  public static void assertEquals(Collection<?> actual, Collection<?> expected, String message) {
    if (actual == expected) {
      return;
    }

    if (actual == null || expected == null) {
      if (message != null) {
        fail(message);
      } else {
        fail("Collections not equal: expected: " + expected + " and actual: " + actual);
      }
    }

    assertEquals(
        actual.size(),
        expected.size(),
        (message == null ? "" : message + ": ") + "lists don't have the same size");

    Iterator<?> actIt = actual.iterator();
    Iterator<?> expIt = expected.iterator();
    int i = -1;
    while (actIt.hasNext() && expIt.hasNext()) {
      i++;
      Object e = expIt.next();
      Object a = actIt.next();
      String explanation = "Lists differ at element [" + i + "]: " + e + " != " + a;
      String errorMessage = message == null ? explanation : message + ": " + explanation;
      assertEqualsImpl(a, e, errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

This is trying to be helpful but is poor for a number of reasons.

Two equals collections can appear to be different.

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>();
a.add(82);
a.add(100);
System.err.println(a);
Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 82; i <= 100; i++)
    b.add(i);
for (int i = 83; i <= 99; i++)
    b.remove(i);
System.err.println(b);
System.err.println("a.equals(b) && b.equals(a) is " + (a.equals(b) && b.equals(a)));
assertEquals(a, b, "a <=> b");
```

and

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>();
a.add(100);
a.add(82);
System.err.println(a);
Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>(32);
b.add(100);
b.add(82);
System.err.println(b);
System.err.println("a.equals(b) && b.equals(a) is " + (a.equals(b) && b.equals(a)));
assertEquals(a, b, "a <=> b");
```

prints

```
[82, 100]
[100, 82]
a.equals(b) && b.equals(a) is true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: a <=> b: Lists differ at element [0]: 100 != 82
    at ....
```

Two collections can be the same or different depending on how they are compared.

```
assertEquals(a, (Iterable) b); // passes

assertEquals(a, (Object) b); // passes

assertEquals(Arrays.asList(a), Arrays.asList(b)); // passes
```

Comment: It's calling this overload: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/Assert.java#L994

Comment: @marstran ouch, so the type of the reference rather than the object changes the behaviour.

Comment: Yep. The overload should have another name imho. Like `assertSameElements` or something.

Comment: @marstran or assertEquals(Object,Object) should check at runtime but even then it's really only good for List not Set

Comment: @AxelH This function is bad other reasons, but that fact that it considers `null == null` is perfectly consistent with the rest of the language.

Comment: Why not opening an issue? Or better, proposing a fix?

Answer (score 6):

Because for collection only content is compared, not collection type.

Rationale behind it is that often some subclass of collection is returned from tested method and is irrelevant what exactly subclass is used.

Answer (score 2):

When I run below code the condition is `false`.

```
if( (new HashSet<>()).equals(new ArrayList<>())){
            System.out.println("They are equal");
        }
```

Hence for `assertEquals`, it is **true** that it only checks elements and its order for equality. But for `equals` it is **false**.