# Junit test fails after exchanging implementation with stream API, why?

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have implemented the following method that provides an overview over `String`s and their occurrences in the values of a `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getValueItemOccurrences(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    Map<String, Long> occurrencesOfValueItems = new HashMap<>();

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        value.forEach(item -> {
            if (occurrencesOfValueItems.containsKey(item)) {
                occurrencesOfValueItems.put(item, occurrencesOfValueItems.get(item) + 1);
            } else {
                occurrencesOfValueItems.put(item, 1L);
            }
        });
    });

    return occurrencesOfValueItems;
}
```

I have tested it with a single JUnit test and the test succeeds. Here it is (**now also including the imports**):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

class TryoutTest {

    static Map<String, List<String>> items = new HashMap<>();
    static List<String> largeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> mediumList = new ArrayList<String>();       
    static List<String> smallList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> differentLargeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> differentSmallList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> justAList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        largeList.add("Alfred");
        largeList.add("Bakari");
        largeList.add("Christian");
        largeList.add("Dong");
        largeList.add("Etienne");
        largeList.add("Francesco");
        largeList.add("Guido");
        largeList.add("Henrik");
        largeList.add("Ivan");
        largeList.add("Jos");
        largeList.add("Kumar");
        largeList.add("Leonard");
        largeList.add("Marcin");
        largeList.add("Nico");
        largeList.add("Olof");
        items.put("fifteen-01", largeList);

        mediumList.add("Petar");
        mediumList.add("Quentin");
        mediumList.add("Renato");
        mediumList.add("Sadio");
        mediumList.add("Tomislav");
        mediumList.add("Ulrich");
        mediumList.add("Volkan");
        mediumList.add("Wladimir");
        items.put("eight-01", mediumList);

        smallList.add("Xavier");
        smallList.add("Yves");
        smallList.add("Zinedine");
        smallList.add("Alfred");
        items.put("four-01", smallList);

        differentLargeList.add("Bakari");
        differentLargeList.add("Christian");
        differentLargeList.add("Dong");
        differentLargeList.add("Etienne");
        differentLargeList.add("Francesco");
        differentLargeList.add("Xavier");
        differentLargeList.add("Yves");
        differentLargeList.add("Wladimir");
        differentLargeList.add("Jens");
        differentLargeList.add("Hong");
        differentLargeList.add("Le");
        differentLargeList.add("Leigh");
        differentLargeList.add("Manfred");
        differentLargeList.add("Anders");
        differentLargeList.add("Rafal");
        items.put("fifteen-02", differentLargeList);

        differentSmallList.add("Dario");
        differentSmallList.add("Mohammad");
        differentSmallList.add("Abdul");
        differentSmallList.add("Alfred");
        items.put("four-02", differentSmallList);

        anotherList.add("Kenneth");
        anotherList.add("Hong");
        anotherList.add("Bakari");
        anotherList.add("Ulrich");
        anotherList.add("Henrik");
        anotherList.add("Bernd");
        anotherList.add("Samuel");
        anotherList.add("Ibrahim");
        items.put("eight-02", anotherList);

        someList.add("Kumar");
        someList.add("Konrad");
        someList.add("Bakari");
        someList.add("Francesco");
        someList.add("Leigh");
        someList.add("Yves");
        items.put("six-01", someList);

        justAList.add("Bakari");
        items.put("one-01", justAList);
    }

    @Test
    void valueOccurrencesTest() {
        Map<String, Integer> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("Abdul", 1);
        expected.put("Alfred", 3);
        expected.put("Anders", 1);
        expected.put("Bakari", 5);
        expected.put("Bernd", 1);
        expected.put("Christian", 2);
        expected.put("Dario", 1);
        expected.put("Dong", 2);
        expected.put("Etienne", 2);
        expected.put("Francesco", 3);
        expected.put("Guido", 1);
        expected.put("Henrik", 2);
        expected.put("Hong", 2);
        expected.put("Ibrahim", 1);
        expected.put("Ivan", 1);
        expected.put("Jens", 1);
        expected.put("Jos", 1);
        expected.put("Kenneth", 1);
        expected.put("Konrad", 1);
        expected.put("Kumar", 2);
        expected.put("Le", 1);
        expected.put("Leigh", 2);
        expected.put("Leonard", 1);
        expected.put("Manfred", 1);
        expected.put("Marcin", 1);
        expected.put("Mohammad", 1);
        expected.put("Nico", 1);
        expected.put("Olof", 1);
        expected.put("Petar", 1);
        expected.put("Quentin", 1);
        expected.put("Rafal", 1);
        expected.put("Renato", 1);
        expected.put("Sadio", 1);
        expected.put("Samuel", 1);
        expected.put("Tomislav", 1);
        expected.put("Ulrich", 2);
        expected.put("Volkan", 1);
        expected.put("Wladimir", 2);
        expected.put("Xavier", 2);
        expected.put("Yves", 3);
        expected.put("Zinedine", 1);
        assertThat(FunctionalMain.getValueItemOccurrences(items), is(expected));
    }
}
```

When I change the implementation of the method to

```
public static Map<String, Long> getValueItemOccurrences(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

the test case fails, stating that the resulting map is not equal to the expected one. See this eclipse screenshot, which shows that, obviously, the order of elements makes the test fail:

[image]

Is it really just that? I think I have read that `HashMap`s generally don't guarantee any order of keys.

**My (quite long) question is: What can I do to make the stream API call produce a result that passes the test or do I have to change the test case, maybe use a different assertion?**

Some sub-questions are:

- is there an alternative/better way to use the stream API for this method?
- Do I have to return a specific `Map` implementation if order matters (`TreeMap`, maybe)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** your test is broken, fix that.

First of all this is more easy to re-produce with:

```
List<String> list = ImmutableList.of("Kumar", "Kumar", "Jens");

public static Map<String, Long> getValueItemOccurrences1(List<String> list) {
    return list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}

public static Map<String, Long> getValueItemOccurrences2(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Long> occurrencesOfValueItems = new HashMap<>();

    list.forEach(item -> {
        if (occurrencesOfValueItems.containsKey(item)) {
            occurrencesOfValueItems.put(item, occurrencesOfValueItems.get(item) + 1);
        } else {
            occurrencesOfValueItems.put(item, 1L);
        }
    });

    return occurrencesOfValueItems;
}
```

The problem is that after the internal `HashMap::hash` (also called re-hash) and getting the last bits that actually matter when deciding which bucket to choose, they have the same values:

```
    System.out.println(hash("Kumar".hashCode()) & 15);
    System.out.println(hash("Jens".hashCode()) & 15);
```

In simpler words, a `HashMap` decides where to put an entry (bucket is chosen) based on the `hashCode` of your entries. Well, almost, once the `hashCode` is computed, internally there is another `hash` done - to better disperse entries. That final `int` value of the `hashCode` is used to decide the bucket. When you create a HashMap with a default capacity of `16` (via `new HashMap` for example), only the last 4 bits matter where an entry will go (that is why I did the `& 15` there - to see the last 4 bits).

where `hash` is :

```
// xor first 16 and last 16 bits
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

Now, it turns out that `["Kumar" and "Jens"]` *or* `["Xavier", "Kenneth", "Samuel"]` have the same last 4 digits after the algorithm above is applied (3 in the first case and 1 in the second case).

Now that we know this info, this actually can be simplified even further:

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Kumar", 2L);
map.put("Jens", 1L);

System.out.println(map); // {Kumar=2, Jens=1}

map = new HashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("Kumar", x -> 2L);
map.computeIfAbsent("Jens", x -> 1L);
System.out.println(map); // {Jens=1, Kumar=2}
```

I've used `map.computeIfAbsent` because this is what `Collectors.groupingBy` is using under the hood.

---

It turns out that `put` and `computeIfAbsent`, put elements in the `HashMap` using a different way; this is totally allowed as a Map does not have any order anyway - and these elements end up in the same bucket anyway, which is the import part. So test your code, key by key, the previous testing code was broken.

---

This is even funner reading if you want:

`HashMap::put` will add elements in a `Linked` fashion (until `Tree` entries are created), so if you have one element existing, all others will be added like:

```
one --> next --> next ... so on.
```

elements are appended to the `end of this queue` as they come in to the `put` method.

On the other hand `computeIfAbsent` is a bit different, it adds elements to the beginning of the queue. If we take the example above, first `Xavier` is added. Then, when `Kenneth` is added, becoming the first:

```
 Kenneth -> Xavier // Xavier was "first"
```

When `Samuel` is added, it becomes the first:

```
 Samuel -> [Kenneth -> Xavier]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would this matter? A `Map` is defined to be equal to another if `map1.entrySet().equals(map2.entrySet())`. A `Set` is equal to another if they are the same size with the same elements (according to `equals`). And a `Map.Entry` is equal to another if the keys are equal and the values are equal (according to `equals`). Why would _how_ the elements are added make a difference?

Comment: @Slaw that depends on how `assertThat` and `is` is handling that internally and I don't know this part. that test could have been written as `leftMap.equals(rightMap) == true`

Comment: @Slaw this would not be the first time `testNG` [does something fishy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201814/why-are-empty-collections-of-different-type-equal) and this looks like testNG code to me...

Comment: Well, instead of `leftMap.equals(rightMap) == true`, you should simply write `leftMap.equals(rightMap)`, but the matchers provide more meaningful error message on mismatches. Looking at [all variants of is(…)](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/index-all.html#_I_), they all refer to [`equalTo`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalTo(T)) which refers to the standard object equality with only an exception for arrays. So the test should not depend on `HashMap` internals.

Comment: I have added the import statements of the test class to the question code. `assertThat` and `is` are from `hamcrest`.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you start using AssertJ instead of JUnit's built-in assertions.
Doing that, you could have used the following AssertJ assertion:

```
assertThat(FunctionalMain.getValueItemOccurrences(items))containsOnly(expected);
```

[`containsOnly()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/MapAssert.html#containsOnly(java.util.Map.Entry...)) checks that your maps have exactly the same elements in any order

Besides that advantage, AssertJ's `assertThat()` also utilizes fluid syntax (unlike JUnit's built-in assertThat), so that your IDE can give you context sensitive help to let you know which of AssertJ's hundreds of type-specific assertions are available for your tested value.